# Why are ARIMA(p,d,q) models never stationary with d$\neq$0?

Tags: time-series, arima, stationarity

I've been told that it's a consequence of there being a root of one in the characteristic polynomial, but I've not found any explanations beyond this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have ARIMA(0,1,0) a.k.a. I(1):
$$\Delta x_t=\varepsilon_t$$
Let's see what's the variance at step $t$, but first get the value:
$$x_t=x_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t=x_{t-2}+\varepsilon_t+\varepsilon_{t-1}=\dots=x_0+\sum_{s=1}^t\varepsilon_s$$
We know that errors are uncorrelated, so the variance is
$$\sigma^2=Var[x_t]=\sum_{s=1}^t\sigma_\varepsilon^2=t\sigma_\varepsilon^2$$
You see that the variance is growing with $t$. This means that I(1) is nonstationary.

This is how it works. You can extend this to any ARIMA(p,d,q)